# Finding the error in my code for parsing JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I've googled for hours and checked documentation, but I can't seem to find what's wrong with my jQuery... I'm trying to practice reading a local JSON file and displaying the contents in my HTML's body.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON( "test.json", function( data ) {
        var items = [];
        $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
            items.push( "<li id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>" );
            console.log(data); 
        });
        $( "<ul/>", {
            "class": "my-new-list",
            html: items.join( "" )
        }).appendTo( "body" );
    });

});
```

and Heres the actual json file in the same folder:

```
{
  "one": "Singular sensation",
  "two": "Beady little eyes",
  "three": "Little birds pitch by my doorstep"
}
```

I only get a blank body when i open the index.html. The index.html has

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/JavaScript" src="script.js"></script>
```

so I know it shouldn't be a problem with my linking....

UPDATE: 
Heres my new output from the console now:

```
 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/Steven/Desktop/meltApplication/test.json.    Received an invalid response. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Comment: If you `console.log(data)` do you see the expected object?

Comment: I don't see the expected object, in fact, I get errors (?).

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND file://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined script.js:1

Comment: When you leave out the protocol prefix on a URL, it uses the same protocol as used to load the main page. So you can't access a CDN that way if you access your `index.html` locally, you have to get the `index.html` from a webserver.

Comment: AJAX uses an XHR request. An XML **HTTP** Request. You cannot directly access the file system through HTTP requests from the browser. This is doomed to failure. You need a proper web server, serving content over HTTP.

Comment: Just realized that with some searching, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//: means use the same schema as that of the current page, so if you have opened your file locally (if the URL in the address bar is file://...), your schema is file://, so the script will look for JQuery on your local machine as the error indicates.

do what @Melvinr said to load JQuery properly, then you can continue debugging the rest of your code.

Comment: The next problem is that Ajax and "local filesystem" don't mix.

Answer (score 0):

You're not adding the http protocol, so it means the browser will try to find the js locally

Use this to add the jquery reference

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You're not adding the http: protocol, so it means the browser will try to find the js locally

Comment: I meant in your answer ;) Code-only answers are bad, they should be accompanied by explanation.